# make a client redirection with CURL

Tags: php, url, post, curl, redirect

this is what I'm trying to do:

- pass a form with a curl statement using POST variable => good
- after i'm logged in the website go to whichever page I want => not good

here is my script for now:

```
$postData = array(
    'login' => 'john',
    'pwd' => 'doe'
);

$array_url = array('3109');

foreach ($array_url as $k => $i) {
    echo $i."<br>";
    $c = curl_init();

    $url = "http://mywebsite/index.php?ok=1";

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

    $output = curl_exec($c);
    if ($output === false) {
        trigger_error('Erreur curl : ' . curl_error($c), E_USER_WARNING);
    }
    else {

        var_dump($output);
        echo $output;
    }
    curl_close($c);
}
```

How can I achieve this ?

edit: If I try to fetch the page I would like to consult I get redirect to the login form cause I can't set the couple login/pass from this page, I need to fetch the checkingpassword one...

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to determine how the remote page is authenticating sessions.  Most sites do this using a cookie. Once you've logged in, any consecutive page requests pass the cookie, the remote site checks the cookie, if it is valid and not expired, it lets you through, otherwise, it kicks you back to the login page (or gives you an error, or whatever).

So if it's a cookie, you need to store the cookie that's returned, and use that in any subsequent curl requests.

Comment: There are the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` & `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options to deal with cookies.

Comment: @Anthony ok you right, it s checking the phpsessid from the cookie every page, so finally I don't need to bother passing the login form I juste have to retrieve server side (this is my website) the cookie value and provide it to the curl with the instruction hakre gave me ?

Comment: The first curl request passes in the credentials and passes back the cookie.  Every following curl request should just need the cookie, using the options mentioned by hakre.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Zend_Http_Client - it's a part of Zend Framework. It can store cookies and resend them on each next request. Here is example from [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.advanced.html):

```
// To turn cookie stickiness on, set a Cookie Jar
$client->setCookieJar();

// First request: log in and start a session
$client->setUri('http://example.com/login.php');
$client->setParameterPost('user', 'h4x0r');
$client->setParameterPost('password', '1337');
$client->request('POST');

// The Cookie Jar automatically stores the cookies set
// in the response, like a session ID cookie.

// Now we can send our next request - the stored cookies
// will be automatically sent.
$client->setUri('http://example.com/read_member_news.php');
$client->request('GET');
```